# Adding Remember Me functionality in already configured spring OUTH and usernamepassword token authentication system

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have the following spring security configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">


<!-- For S2OAuth endpoints -->
<http   pattern="/oauth/token" 
        create-session="stateless" 
        authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager" 
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
</http>

<http use-expressions="true">
    <!-- Authentication policy -->
    <form-login login-page="/signin" login-processing-url="/signin/authenticate" authentication-failure-url="/signin?error=1" />
    <logout logout-url="/signout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    <!-- Remember Me -->
    <remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" key="myRememberMeKey" />
    <!-- Authorization policy definition: TODO consider replacing with @Secured on @Controllers -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/members/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/groups/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/pubsub/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/signup" access="permitAll" requires-channel="#{environment['application.secureChannel']}" />   
    <intercept-url pattern="/signin" access="permitAll" requires-channel="#{environment['application.secureChannel']}" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/signin/*" access="permitAll" requires-channel="#{environment['application.secureChannel']}" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/reset" access="permitAll" requires-channel="#{environment['application.secureChannel']}" />
    <!-- TODO this would probably be better mapped to simply /invite?token={token} but not able to vary security policy here based on presence of a request parameter.  Consider @Secured on @Controller. -->               
    <intercept-url pattern="/invite/accept" access="permitAll" requires-channel="#{environment['application.secureChannel']}" />
    <!-- TODO this should be restricted to admin users only -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="permitAll" />           
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" requires-channel="#{environment['application.secureChannel']}" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER" />
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="usernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcRememberMeRepository" class="com.springsource.greenhouse.rememberme.JdbcRememberMeRepository" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"/>
<bean id="coreUserDetailsService" class="com.springsource.greenhouse.rememberme.RememberMeUserDetailsService" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"/>

<bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
  <property name="tokenRepository" ref="jdbcRememberMeRepository" />
  <property name="userDetailsService" ref="coreUserDetailsService" />
  <property name="key" value="myRememberMeKey" />
  <property name="alwaysRemember" value="true" />
</bean>


<!-- For S2OAuth endpoints -->
<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="realmName" value="greenhouseApi" />
</beans:bean>


<beans:import resource="security-oauth-provider.xml" />

 </beans:beans>
```

When I tick the remember-me checkbox , I see my remember-me database is populated as shown in the snapshot. Now I close the browser and try to access the url which needs sign-in. I am able to see the page. Now here I am confused about whether I am able to see the page because of login or because of remember-me. Secondly I see in the remember-me database table the last date is not updated. What can be the reasons for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting your browser is not enough. To test remember me functionality you need to be sure that your session is expired. If **lastUsed** was not updated then it means that remember me functionality was not used. In your case HTTP session was active. You need to deactivate it and there are multiple options to do it:

- wait for session expiration. Hint: you can set minimal session timeout, for example set 1 minute in your web.xml.
- or remove session cockie (do not remove all coockies for your domain, remember me use coockie too)
- or stop your application server then clean up a directory where it persist session data and start it again. For tomcat it is tomcat_root/work.

Setting up session timeout value to 1 minute in web.xml:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: Cool Thanks. I removed the cookie from the browser . After removing the cookie i was redirected to the login page again. I am not sure why the remember me is not been called. Any clues.?

Comment: Make a brakepoint in RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(...). Is you configuration is OK and this filter is called? If it's true then you can debug it and find a cause.